# Using Angular [ngClass] with boolean var

Tags: angular, css

I have an Angular 5 website with this page that has a filter icon bar. I'm trying to apply the additional `filter-selected` css class once the user clicks the icon - and of course turn it off when clicked again.

I'm attempting to use the `hostFilter` var to turn on/off, but without success.
And yes, I have initialized this var in my component :

```
  hostFilter = false;
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="node-selection">  
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Hosts" (click)="hostFilter!=hostFilter; rebuildTrees(1)">
            <i [ngClass]="{                
                'selected-node square host filter-selected' : hostFilter,
                'selected-node square host' : true
                }">
            </i>
        </a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Host Access Points" (click)="rebuildTrees(2)"><i class="selected-node square host-access"></i></a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Storages" (click)="rebuildTrees(5)"><i class="selected-node circle storage"></i></a>
    </div>    
</div>
```

```css
<style>
.selected-node.square.host {
        background-color: #40923b;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: wheat;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;        
    }
.selected-node.square.host.filter-selected {
      box-shadow: 
      0 1px 2px #fff, 
      0 -1px 1px #666,
      inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 
      inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}
</style>
```

Here's what it looks like by default:

[image]

And if I force it to appear, it looks like this:

[image]

Advice is appreciated...

---

***** **UPDATE** ********

I updated my `(click)` event code as per answer below. My logical operator `!` was in the wrong place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `(click)` listener function on the anchor tag isn't doing anything. `hostFilter!=hostFilter` is just going to always be false; it's not assigning a value. What you want to do to toggle the value is:

`(click)="hostFilter = !hostFilter"`

Past that, you can ditch the `[ngClass]` binding a whole object. Just give the element the classes it should always have and use a class binding on the 'toggleable' class:

`<i class="selected-node square host" [class.filter-selected]="hostFilter"> </i>`

Comment: oh right. I clearly transposd the `!=` by mistake. Thanks for pointing that out. I meant to type `!hostFilter`.

Comment: Indeed, as bc1105 also pointed out, using class binding is much clearer for my case. And indeed once I fixed my `(click)` error it all worked find - even with my convoluted `[ngClass]` binding.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be:

`<i class="selected-node square host" [class.filter-selected]="hostFilter"></i>`